# solid generated by revolving $y=2$ bounded by region $y^2\leq 2x , x \leq 8$ and $y\geq 2 $ is -

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The volume of the solid generated by revolving about the horizontal line $y=2$ bounded by region $y^2\leq 2x , x \leq 8$  and $y\geq 2 $  is -

(1) $2\sqrt {2\pi}$

(2) $\frac{28 \pi}{3}$

(3) $84 \pi$ .

(4) None of these .

I think this problem is solved by using the "Washer method " using the formula 
$Volume=\int_{a}^{b} \pi( R(x)^2-r(x)^2) $ where $R(x)=$ outer radius and $r(x)=$ inner radius .

i our problem i think $a=2 ,b=4 $ nad $R(x)=8 , r(x)=\sqrt{2x} $ . How ever i think $R(x) $ and $r(x) $ expressions are right .

I will manage if i know how to find the correct expression for $R(x) , r(x)$.

Complete solution will be highly appreciated . Thank you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea in using the "washer method". Since it is revolving around a horizontal line, the volume is given by
$$ \int_a^b \pi[R(x)^2 - r(x)^2]\, dx, $$
where $R(x)$ and $r(x)$ are the outer and inner radius respectively, and $a, b$ are the $x$-values where the cross section starts and ends. In this case, $b=8$ and $a$ can be obtained by solving for $x$ the system $y^2=2x$ and $y=2$, which gives $a=2$. Upon sketching out the given region, you will see that the inner radius is 0 and the outer radius is
$$ R(x) = \sqrt{2x} - 2. $$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
V & = \int_2^8 \pi(\sqrt{2x}-2)^2\, dx 
\end{align*}
and you should be able to carry it from here (: I did the integration and the answer I got is:

> \begin{equation} V = \frac{28\pi}{3}.\end{equation}

Comment: Not sure about this... aren't you revolving it around the line $y=0$?

Comment: @RafaBudría It would be around $y=0$ if my outer radius is $R(x)=\sqrt{2x}$ instead, hence the $-2$ in $R(x)$ because the question says to revolve around $y=2$.

Comment: Sorry, I see it now, it's the square of the difference, not the difference of squares.